# Spring Retry maxAttempts does not behave

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

A very simple HelloWorld Test

```java
@Log4j2
@Service
@EnableRetry
@EnableScheduling
public class MyBeanImpl {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/2 * *  * * ? ")
    @Retryable(value = {RuntimeException.class}, maxAttempts = 4, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000))
    public void sched() {
        log.info("Foo sched a = {}", a++);
        throw new RuntimeException("Foo");
    }    
}


@Recover
public void recover(RuntimeException e) {
//.....
}

// Junit Class is here , For Simple POC test, I dont use Interface class, just use Implementation class
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Log4j2
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyBeanImplTest {
@Autowired    
MyBeanImpl _myBean;

private String input = "HelloWorld";

@Test
public void sched() {
_myBean.sched();
}
```

Question :

I set maxAttempts = 1, it runs 1 time. why?

I set maxAttempts = 2, it always run 3 times. why?

I set maxAttempts = 4, however it runs 8 times. why?

I set maxAttempts = 6, it runs 11 times. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because it is scheduled as well as being called by the test case.

Look at the thread name in the INFO log.

Comment: As I am new to Spring Retry and Spring Scheduled. I follow your advice and enable debug level, I find there is another thread. In my case it is called my-scheduled-task-pool, and the pool size is set to **10**.

Sorry for my stupid mistake.

```java
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;
//....
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-scheduled-task-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```